# Is it rude to ask “do you want one” to an adult?

Tags: politeness

Is it rude to ask “do you want one” if you’re trying to ask if an adult also wants something? (ex: food) I’m worried if this would sound rude or disrespectful.

Comment: I think we'd need more context to understand why you might think it sounds rude. It sounds fine, but in some contexts "Would you like one" would be slightly more polite.

Answer (score 2):

I’m confused why this would appear rude, but to my ears, no, it’s not rude. It seems to be a very basic, broadly applicable question. I see no connection to age— it’s not as if this phrase is only used for children… Did you have an alternative, “less rude” phrase in mind? Or an example that made you think it might be rude?